# Length of Object map actionscript

Tags: actionscript, dictionary, iteration

I have an object using as a map in actionscript

```
var map:Object = new Object();

map[1] = "one";
map[2] = "one";
```

Is there any easy way to get length of map without iterating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may not be better, but I think it's easier to use ObjectUtil...

```
import mx.utils.ObjectUtil;
ObjectUtil.getClassInfo(map).properties.length;
```

That would return 2 in your case.

Answer (score 1):

No, the easiest way is iterating the map.